# Seating plan in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code something like this. It's like seating plan in cinema.

```
Row 1 ###############

Row 2 ###############

Row 3 ###############
```

Till 15th row and each row have 15 places represented by : #

I did this using many "print" but that's too long.

The position of each # must be a list. And if someone choose a seat for example 15th seat in 2nd row than the # Should be replaced by a *.

I just want to know how can I do this using While or For and a list instead of printing # 15 times?

Here is my code:

```
def MenuPrincipal():
    print("1. Afficher les places disponibles ")
    print("2. Afficher les tarifs")
    print("3. Afficher le total des ventes")
    print("4. Acheter un billet")
    print("5. Quitter")
    print()

def Place():
    Rang1 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang2 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang3 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang4 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang5 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang6 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang7 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang8 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang9 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang10 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang11 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang12 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang13 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang14 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    Rang15 = ('#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#')
    print("Rangé\t1\t",Rang1[0],Rang1[1],Rang1[2],Rang1[3],Rang1[4],Rang1[5],Rang1[6],
          Rang1[7],Rang1[8],Rang1[9],Rang1[10],Rang1[11],Rang1[12],Rang1[13],Rang1[14],Rang1[15],Rang1[16],Rang1[17],Rang1[18],Rang1[19],Rang1[20],
            Rang1[21],Rang1[22],Rang1[23],Rang1[24],Rang1[25],Rang1[26],Rang1[27],Rang1[28],Rang1[29],sep='')    
    print("Rangé\t2\t",Rang2[0],Rang2[1],Rang2[2],Rang2[3],Rang2[4],Rang2[5],Rang2[6],
          Rang2[7],Rang2[8],Rang2[9],Rang2[10],Rang2[11],Rang2[12],Rang2[13],Rang2[14],Rang2[15],Rang2[16],Rang2[17],Rang2[18],Rang2[19],Rang2[20],
            Rang2[21],Rang2[22],Rang2[23],Rang2[24],Rang2[25],Rang2[26],Rang2[27],Rang2[28],Rang2[29],sep='')    
MenuPrincipal()
Choix1 = input("Veuillez SVP choisir une option (1 – 5):")

if Choix1 == '5':
    exit
elif Choix1 == '1':
    Place()
```

I haven't finish yet but I going to explain what is happening.

We have 5 Options.

1st Option: Shows a map of seating and also availability of seats.

2nd option: Shows the price per row. for example first row= 200$, 2nd row = 180$ and so on.

3rd option: Shows total sale.

4th option: Gives an option to chose a specific seat and buy ticket.

5th option: Quit the program.

Note that the program should not end if we don't select 5th option.

Comment: Sounds like homework, show us what you tried.

Comment: yes I can. It's in French actually but Im going to translate it. Just give me a min to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save(sales, taken_seats):
    #code here to save sales and taken seats to the file.
    f = open("data.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(sales) + "\n")
    for x in taken_seats:
        f.write(x + "\n")
    f.close()
def load():
    #code here to load the sales total and currently purchased seats.
    f = open("data.txt")
    sales = f.readline().replace("\n", "")
    taken_seats = []
    d = True
    while d == True:
        line = f.readline().replace("\n", "")
        if line == "":
            d = False
        else:
            taken_seats.append(line)
    if sales == "":
        sales = 0
    else:
        sales = int(sales)
    f.close()
    return (int(sales), taken_seats)

def display_seats(taken_seats):
    seating = []
    for xd in range(15):
        row = []
        xda = 0
        for xda in range(15):
            row.append("#")
        seating.append(row)
    for x in taken_seats:
        pos = x.split(",")
        seating[(int(pos[0]) - 1)][(int(pos[1]))] = "X"
    dx = 1
    for row in seating:
        if len(str(dx)) < 2:
            de = " " + str(dx)
        else:
            de = dx
        print ("Row: " + str(de) + " ".join(row))
        dx = dx + 1
def list_options():
    print ("5: exit")
    print ("4: buy ticket")
    print ("3: view sales")
    print ("2: view price per row")
    print ("1: view current seating")
    new_input = input("Your choice: ")
    return (new_input)
def purchase_seat(taken_seats):
    print ("Would you like to view current seating availability? ")
    print ("'1' = yes, '2' = no")
    newinput = input("? ")
    if newinput == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    x = True
    while x == True:
        cost = 0
        print ("what row would you like to buy a seat on? ")
        rowx = input("What row? ")
        print ("What seat would you like to purchase?")
        rowy = input("what seat? ")
        d = (str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy))
        h = 0
        for x in taken_seats:
            if d == x:
                h = 1
        if h == 1:
            print ("That seat is already taken, please choose another seat.")
        elif int(rowx) > 15 or int(rowy) > 15:
            print ("Invalid seating location, please choose another seat.")
        else:
            print ("seat purchased.")
            cost = (200 - (10 * int(rowx)))
            x = False
    return (cost, (str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)))
da = load()
sales = da[0]
taken_seats = da[1]
quitter = 0
while quitter == 0:
    new_input = list_options()
    if new_input == "5":
        save(sales, taken_seats)
        quitter = 1
    elif new_input == "4":
        g = True
        while g == True:
            new_seat = purchase_seat(taken_seats)
            taken_seats.append(new_seat[1])
            print ("That will be: $ " + str(new_seat[0]))
            sales = sales + new_seat[0]
            print ("Would you like to purchase another seat?")
            new_input = input("'1' = yes, '2' = no: ")
            if new_input == "1":
                pass
            else:
                g = False
    elif new_input == "3":
        print ("Total sales: $" + str(sales))
    elif new_input == "2":
        xd = 0
        while xd < 15:
            print ("Row " + str(xd + 1) + ": is $" + str((200 - (10 * xd)) - 10))
            xd = xd + 1
    elif new_input == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    else:
        print ("invalid option.")
```

A zip file including the script with file saving can be found at:
[Download seating.zip](http://www.gaelephor.com/published/seating.zip)

Comment: when I select a number like 1 or 2. It says invalid choice? How do I select an option?

Comment: @Alpha are you on python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: i'm using spyder that comes with Anaconda. I think it's the 3

Comment: @Alpha ok. I updated the above code to work with it then. input() was returning a string not a int, I reflected that by comparing to "1" rather than 1 etc.

Comment: hold on a sec few more errors to fix

Comment: oh I see alright :)

Comment: Done, the calculation for seat prices was trying to multiply a string as well :/    thanks for your patience! let me know if you have any more errors

Comment: let me check ill be back

Comment: Hi your code is working grate. But When I select a seat (for example: 1st row 5th seat). That seat must be booked and I should not be able to select it again. While in your code I can still select the same seat. Also when the user choose the 4th option to buy ticket, I want another question that asks him if he wants to see the seat map while selecting seats. And finally when he have selected a specific seat, he must be asked again if he want to buy another seat with (yes or no). I need your help to this please?

Comment: @Alpha The code has been updated to include your new requests, let me know if that is what you wanted, or if their is anything else you would like included.      Also, would you be interested in seeing a version that saves and loads the purchased seats from a file? (that way every time the program is run, the sales_total and the purchased seats aren't reset.)

Comment: @Alpha I have included a link to a download for a zip file that has the code with file saving, check it out :)     The zip file has 3 files, main.py that has the code for the program, data.txt, which is an empty text file for the program to save and load data from, and clear_saved_data.py which is a script that automatically clears all the saved data.  Hope its helpful!

Comment: hey thank you very much i'm going to check this and ill be back to let you know if everything is working right :)

Comment: I executed your code and when I want to select a seat that is available it says "The seat is already taken. Choose another seat". I get this message every time I tried for many seats but still the same message.

Comment: @Alpha I changed the logic for the comparison, please redownload and try it again, it should work now. sorry about that.

Comment: You did it it's working grate as it should be :D. I don't know how I can thank you but you saved my life. Thanks so much :D

Comment: Can you solve this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134633/tic-tac-toe-wincheck-def

Comment: @Alpha As requested:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134633/tic-tac-toe-wincheck-def/41145180#41145180    Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def display(taken_seats):
    seating = []
    xd = 0
    while xd < 15: #creates the cinema seating map
        row = []
        xda = 0
        while xda < 15:
            row.append("#")
            xda = xda + 1
        xd = xd + 1
        seating.append(row)
    for x in taken_seats: #changes the seats that are taken to a "X"
        pos = x.split(",")
        seating[(int(pos[0]) - 1)][(int(pos[1]))] = "X"
    dx = 1
    for row in seating: #prints the rows.
        if len(str(dx)) < 2:
            de = " " + str(dx)
        else:
            de = dx
        print "Row: " + str(de) + " ".join(row)
        dx = dx + 1




taken_seats = ("1,12", "2,8", "5,5", "12,12")

display(taken_seats)
```

all purchased seats are put in the list "taken_seats" in the format row#,seat#

hope this helped! (my apologies for it not being the cleanest, its mainly filled with iterators.)

EDIT:

to add additional seats, simply do

```
taken_seats.append("10,10")
```

changing the numbers to the desired seating position.

to display the updated seating, simply run the command

```
display(taken_seats)
```

code with a menu interface:

```
def display_seats(taken_seats):
    seating = []
    for xd in range(15):
        row = []
        xda = 0
        for xda in range(15):
            row.append("#")
        seating.append(row)
    for x in taken_seats:
        pos = x.split(",")
        seating[(int(pos[0]) - 1)][(int(pos[1]))] = "X"
    dx = 1
    for row in seating:
        if len(str(dx)) < 2:
            de = " " + str(dx)
        else:
            de = dx
        print ("Row: " + str(de) + " ".join(row))
        dx = dx + 1
def list_options():
    print ("5: exit")
    print ("4: buy ticket")
    print ("3: view sales")
    print ("2: view price per row")
    print ("1: view current seating")
    new_input = input("Your choice: ")
    return (new_input)
def purchase_seat(taken_seats):
    print ("Would you like to view current seating availability? ")
    print ("'1' = yes, '2' = no")
    newinput = input("? ")
    if newinput == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    x = True
    while x == True:
        cost = 0
        print ("what row would you like to buy a seat on? ")
        rowx = input("What row? ")
        print ("What seat would you like to purchase?")
        rowy = input("what seat? ")
        if any((str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)) for x in taken_seats):
            print ("That seat is already taken, please choose another seat.")
        elif int(rowx) > 15 or int(rowy) > 15:
            print ("Invalid seating location, please choose another seat.")
        else:
            print ("seat purchased.")
            cost = (200 - (10 * int(rowx)))
            x = False
    return (cost, (str(rowx) + "," + str(rowy)))
taken_seats = []
sales = 0
quitter = 0
while quitter == 0:
    new_input = list_options()
    if new_input == "5":
        quitter = 1
    elif new_input == "4":
        g = True
        while g == True:
            new_seat = purchase_seat(taken_seats)
            taken_seats.append(new_seat[1])
            print ("That will be: $ " + str(new_seat[0]))
            sales = sales + new_seat[0]
            print ("Would you like to purchase another seat?")
            new_input = input("'1' = yes, '2' = no: ")
            if new_input == "1":
                pass
            else:
                g = False
    elif new_input == "3":
        print ("Total sales: $" + str(sales))
    elif new_input == "2":
        xd = 0
        while xd < 15:
            print ("Row " + str(xd + 1) + ": is $" + str((200 - (10 * xd)) - 10))
            xd = xd + 1
    elif new_input == "1":
        display_seats(taken_seats)
    else:
        print ("invalid option.")
```

A zip file containing the files and code for the seating and sales to be saved and loaded from a file can be found at [gaelephor.com](http://www.gaelephor.com/published/seating.zip)

Comment: hey thanks i'll look at it. It might take a few moments because I'm new to programming.

Comment: how can I choose a specific seat? according to your code there is no option.

Comment: @Alpha you would use the command "taken_seats.append("10,10")"