# Tic Tac Toe WinCheck Def

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm having some trouble with coding tic tac toe game where the computer plays randomly by choosing numbers between 0 and 1. I tried a code but I get unreal situation like this on represented here:

O O O

X X X

O O O

I want to put something in my code that check if there is a winner at every move. If someone wins I want the game to stop and tell who is the winner or if no one wins. And also I don't want the output to be like in a picture below. I just want one single display of board (if it's possible).

[The output of this programme is that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRpFi.png)

Here is my code:

```
import random

board = []
line= 3
col = 3
for i in range (line) :
    for j in range (col):
        board.append(" ") 


def show():
    print(board[0],'|',board[1],'|',board[2])
    print('--------------')
    print(board[3],'|',board[4],'|',board[5])
    print('--------------')
    print(board[6],'|',board[7],'|',board[8])
    print()

# Verify the possibility of position to take.
B=1
C=2
D=3           
def check(A, B, C, D):
    if board[B] == A and board[C] == A and board[D] == A :
        return True            

# Win conditions
def Winner(G):
    if  check(G, 0, 1, 2):
            True 
    if  check(G, 0, 3, 6):
            True 
    if  check(G, 0, 4, 8):
            True
    if  check(G, 1, 4, 7):
            True             
    if  check(G, 2, 5, 8):
            True         
    if  check(G, 2, 4, 6):
            True     
    if  check(G, 3, 4, 5):
            True 
    if  check(G, 6, 7, 8):
            True  


player1 = "O"
player2 = "X"
play=random.randint(0,1)
if play == 1:
    player1 = "X"
    player2 = "O"

while True:
        random.seed()
        place=random.randint(0,8)
        if board[place] != "O" and board[place] != "X" :
           board[place] = player1
           if Winner(player1)==True:
               print("~~~~~~~ the player ",player1," wins~~~~~~~")           
               break;

           while True:
               random.seed()
               place=random.randint(0,8)

               if board[place] != "O" and board[place] != "X" :
                   board[place] = player2
                   if Winner(player2)==True:
                       print("~~~~~~~ the player ",player2," wins~~~~~~~")           
                       break;

                   break; 

        else: 
            print("This position is already taken")         

        show()
```

Comment: ``True`` as a statement does absolutely nothing.  You need to ``return True`` to actually indicate a win.  (Also, calling ``random.seed()`` inside a loop is a horribly bad idea - one call per run of the program is quite sufficient, or zero since this is already done for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
import random
board = []
for x in range(9):
    board.append(" ")
def show():
    print(board[0],'|',board[1],'|',board[2])
    print('--------------')
    print(board[3],'|',board[4],'|',board[5])
    print('--------------')
    print(board[6],'|',board[7],'|',board[8])
def check(A, B, C, D):
    if board[B] == A and board[C] == A and board[D] == A :
        return True 
def Winner(G):
    ret = False
    if  check(G, 0, 1, 2):
            ret = True 
    if  check(G, 0, 3, 6):
            ret = True 
    if  check(G, 0, 4, 8):
            ret = True
    if  check(G, 1, 4, 7):
            ret = True             
    if  check(G, 2, 5, 8):
            ret = True         
    if  check(G, 2, 4, 6):
            ret = True     
    if  check(G, 3, 4, 5):
            ret = True 
    if  check(G, 6, 7, 8):
            ret = True
    return ret
def filled():
    ll = 0
    for x in board:
        if x == " ":
            ll = 11 + 1
    if ll > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
done = False
turn = "O"
tie = False
while done == False:
    place = random.randint(0, 8)
    if board[place] == " ":
        board[place] = turn
        if Winner(turn) == True:
            done = True
        else:
            if filled() == True:
                done = True
                tie = True
            else:#change turn
                if turn == "X":
                    turn = "O"
                else:
                    turn = "X"
if tie == True:
    print ("The game was a tie. No winner.")
    show()
else:
    print("~~~~~~~ the player '",turn,"' wins~~~~~~~")
    show()
```

This should complete all your requirements.

Just check for winner() and filled() after each valid turn. have the loop change whos turn it is after every successful loop, to prevent duplication.

NOTE: 'O' goes first, to change that change variable turn to 'X' before the loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Winner()` function doesn't return anything, so by default it implicitly returns `False` no matter what the inputs are.  It should include a `return True` instead of just `True` (which does nothing at all), something like:

```
def Winner(G):
    if check(G, 0, 1, 2) or check(G, 0, 3, 6) or check(G, 0, 4, 8) or check(G, 1, 4, 7) or check(G, 2, 5, 8) or check(G, 2, 4, 6) or check(G, 3, 4, 5) or check(G, 6, 7, 8):
        return True
    else
        return False
```

The main point is that is should `return True`.  The rest is mainly just style preference - I prefer a single `if`, with a lot of `or` conditions.  Others may prefer a lot of `if` statements all with `return True`.

(Technically, you don't need the `else` part, as it will effectively return `False` by default anyhow.  But it makes it more readable.  You could also remove just the `else` line, and reverse-indent the `return False` which makes it a catch all for the entire function rather than for the `if`.)

Comment: That's a whole other question.  However, you could run `winner()` for both users (ie, run it twice) and if you get `winner(A) == winner(B)` then that would be a draw.

Comment: And it show the message (player x wins or player O wins) before completing all the position. I want all positions to be filled with O or X before the win message

Comment: Then store the message (result of `winner()`) in a variable, and don't print any message until after the while loop has completed.

Comment: do you mean I rewrite 2 time the function winner for both player?

Comment: No don't write it twice, just run it twice.  You can literally run it as:  `if winner(A) == winner(B):`  Or you may want to run them separately, store the results of each, and then compare the results later.  Depending on how you end up incorporating the changes into your code.

Comment: oh ok ill try that

Comment: am I suppose to put (if WinnerA== WinnerB) in while. I don't where understand where exactly is should put this?

Comment: I reckon you should rewrite your code, and then if you can't solve it with the new code, post a new separate question, including the new code.